# Django Form: When rendering 'js' attribute in Media class, Django calls <script> on each letter of title?

Tags: python, django

I've decided to put together what I need myself—this means that I've to implement some javascript in a Django form.

My current form looks like this:

```
class SoundTestPairForm(forms.Form):
    LANGUAGE_CHOICES = [[d['language'], d['language']] for d in Sound.objects.order_by('language').values('language').distinct()]
    lesson_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    sound_pk = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    master_phrase1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    master_phrase2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    sex = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=Sound.SEX_CHOICES
    )

    starts_with = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=Sound.POS_CHOICES
    )

    language = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES
    )

    user_sound = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=Sound.objects.all(),
    )

    class Media:
        js = ('filter_queryset.js')
```

But when I `form_instance = SoundTestPairForm()` and call `form_instance.media.render`, I get:

```
[u'<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/f"></script>', u'<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/i"></script>', u'<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/l"></script>', u'<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/t"></script>', u'<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/e"></script>', u'<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/r"></script>', u'<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/_"></script>', u'<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/q"></script>', u'<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/u"></script>', u'<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/y"></script>', u'<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/s"></script>', u'<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/"></script>', u'<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/j"></script>']
```

For some reason, it's looking at every letter of the file name instead of the file name as a whole? `render_js()` gives the same result.

Have I found a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a comma to make `js` a tuple.

```
class Media:
    js = ('filter_queryset.js',)
```

Without the comma, `('filter_queryset.js')` is the string `'filter_queryset.js'`.

Comment: ... Boy am I glad the internet exists